# CocoaHTTPServer server not playing video on ios7 issue

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, cocoahttpserver

I have used CocoaHTTPServer server to stream media files. App is playing media with httpURL with MPMusicPlayerController Player controller.
My implementation works fine on older iOS version but fails on iOS7 gets error

```
{
    MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey = 1;
    error = "Error Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-1005
    \"The network connection was lost.\" UserInfo=0xa5427b0
     {NSLocalizedDescription=The   network connection was lost.}";
}
```

I tested to open url in browser I could download file.That means server is running. 
Any idea,suggestion what is going wrong?

Comment: Hi App, have you got solution? Do you have working source code to stream video using CocoaHTTPServer? I would appreciate if you share it with me. Looking forward for your reply.

Comment: I got solution, I changed packet size in CocoaHTTPServer.And it started to work.I can not share source code here.